# How can I fix a toilet flapper that isn't sealing due to mildew buildup?

Tags: toilet

I believe I have pink slime on toilet flapper and "base" of toiler fill valve. The toilet is running. I believe it is not sealing because of the pink slime. Any ideas?

Comment: That's probably not why it isn't sealing. They get old and stiff. Spend a buck and a half on a new one.

Comment: if it's mildew, a splash of bleach in the tank, soaked for an hour or two will zap most of it...

Answer (score 1):

Clean off the pink slime from the flapper and where it seals to the tank, or you could just replace the flapper. They are readily available   at your home store.

Comment: To easily clean it, turn off the water supply and flush the toilet to drain most of the water.

Comment: I gotta go with a new one flappers are cheap, sure cleaning may help but it can make the problem worse.